# Calling JSON.parse on php returned array, some numbers parsed as INT, others parsed as STRING

Tags: javascript, php, json

Looking for an explanation rather than an answer here :) 
I have this php script that is called with jquery's AJAX

```
$query = 'SELECT MONTH(PRSD#) as "Monat", CAST(AVG(GASVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Gas", CAST(AVG(OLVBR) as DECIMAL(10, 3)) as "Öl", CAST(AVG(STROVBR) as DECIMAL(10,3)) as "Strom" FROM swind.gwenergy GROUP BY YEAR(PRSD#), MONTH(PRSD#) ORDER BY MONTH(PRSD#)';
    
    $dbReturn = $database->execute($query, array());
    
    $jsonArray = array();
    
    while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($dbReturn)) {´
        echo json_encode($jsonArray);
    }
```

When I call in the JS side of things:

`let parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);` 
I am returned with this: 
 `{Monat: 2, Gas: '13750.607', Öl: '1447.432', Strom: '3901.051'}` 
How come the `Monat` value is not in quotes? 
I thought that maybe because the `$query` in the php script was returning `DECIMAL(10,3)` but when I replace it with `FLOOR(...` the `JSON.parse` still wrapped the value in quotes. 
 Is this related to the `$query` response, or is this a `JSON.parse` action? 
Look forward to hearing other ideas :) Thanks! -Boogabooga

Comment: What is stored in the database for Monat? Or is it just an Integer you put in?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :) `Monat` is a textfield, but only numbers are being stored in it in the `Y-mm-dd` format, the other fields are also textfields in the MYSQL DB but only numbers are being stored in them too. The `inputs` on the `html` side are also textfields, with regex's to allow only numbers written in them

Comment: _"Is this related to the $query response"_ - well find out, do a `var_dump($row);` and see what you get ...

Comment: @CBroe I var_dumped it and yes it indeed was returning my values as `strings` even though I was calling `Decimal()` on them, just curious as to why that was, because when I call the `Month()` it returned it as an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem.
You can check the data type on PHP with [gettype()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gettype.php)

Note that since PHP 5.3.3, there is a flag for auto-convert numerical numbers when using json_encode.

`echo json_encode( $jsonArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );`

This should do the work for you.

Comment: good answer! thumbs up

Comment: My current fix was to just `parseINT()` in my `JS` when pushing into my array BUT this is a great solution as it skips needing to do that :)